# Natural coordinates of a n-sphere

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, noneuclidean-geometry

I stumbled on [n-spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) recently, and recalled spherical coordinates.

They are very useful for doing computations on spheres embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, but oddly uneven, if not to say ugly, when compared to the intrinsic beauty and symmetry of a sphere.

I wonder, if we forget about the embedding Euclidean space, if there are more symmetric ways to parametrize the points of a n-sphere.

For those who are acquainted with spherical coordinates I feel I have to explain what I dislike about those. Among other tings, $x_1$ depends on $\varphi_1$, but $x_2$ depends on $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$. The domain for $\varphi_1$ is not the domain of $\varphi_{i+1}$. If you look at it from a distance, it looks strange, somehow not right.

So if we start from the geometry of the n-sphere, are there more natural coordinates?

What I've tried so far is to state some properties of the spheres. For every point $p$ there is an *antipode* $\bar p$. There is a metric $d(p,q)$ that corresponds to the length of the arc between the points. (I failed to find an elegant way to proof the triangular equation.) The only point with $d(p,q)=\pi$ is $q=\bar p$. I didn't get far from those basic considerations, and I wonder if all those things already have a name for which I could do a search on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean by saying $n$-spheres are ugly? In what way are they ugly? Edit: I may have misread - did you mean that spherical coordinates are ugly?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: spheres are beautiful (highly symmetric and there are no exceptions or border cases that need extra considerations). Contrary to that, spherical coordinate are plagued with exceptions, the very definition of those is asymmetric.

Comment: There's no nice answer to this question. If you want to use $n$ real numbers to parameterize the sphere, there's either going to be points that you miss, or points that you cover multiple times, or your parameterization will not be continuous.

Comment: @DuncanRamage It would be perfectly OK if the parameters were from $S_1$ or thereabout. Otherwise, there must be a reason why there is no nice solution. Something that pinpoints fundamental topological differences.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Normally, a coordinate map would at least be required to send coordinates to points [homeomorphically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism). Thus you can't get any coordinate map that covers all of $S_n$, for the very fundamental reason that $S_n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ aren't homeomorphic. As for using lower dimensional spheres, for example you can parametrise $S_3$ in terms of the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration#Direct_construction), but I doubt you would find that more appealing...

Comment: Specifically, for $n > 0$, $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic as $S^n$ is compact but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not. If $n = 0$, then they're not homeomorphic, as $|\mathbb{R}^0| = 1$ but $|S^0| = 2$.

Comment: In a way, the Cartesian coordinates $x_1\ldots x_{n+1}$ with $\sum x_i^2=1$ are more symmetric. I take it that you are not happy with those either. Can you provide examples of nice properties that spherical coordinates provide that you's like to see carried over to higher dimensions?

Comment: @A.P. are spherical coordinates a homeomorphism? No, that would be too much to hope for. Hopf fibration is a good point to think about, thank you for that key word and link.